# counting words of each sentence in a long string, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to count the words in each sentence from a long string. What I get is just the number of the sentences. I found some solution in C# and Ruby but they are not for me:-))

I am really new to java-script. Any help much appreciated. The code below:

the output is according:

Words: 1 in sent: 1
Words: 0 in sent: 2
Words: 1 in sent: 3
Words: 1 in sent: 4
Words: 1 in sent: 5
Words: 1 in sent: 6

the word counter is not increasing! Most probably it's something simple.
Thank you in advance.

```
var text1 = $('#textarea1').val();   
var gaps = [];
var wordsC = 0;
var wordsTot = 0;
var tempC = 0;
var sents = text1.split('.');    

for (var elem in sents)
{
    tempC += 1;

    wordsC = elem.split(" ").length;
    wordsTot += wordsC;

    if (tempC == 2) {
        wordsC -= 1;
        wordsTot -= 1;
    }

    document.write("<br />Words:  " + wordsC + " |in sent: " + tempC + "  sent");
};

document.write("<br />words total :    " + wordsTot + "<br />" );
```

Comment: A few notes, [don't use `for...in` to iterate over arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in), it is for iterating over object properties; using it on arrays can do unexpected things. In case you didn't know, JS uses function scope, using `var` to define `elem` in your `for` statement does not limit its scope to the loop. [Don't use `document.write`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Y2Y0U-2qJMs#t=1082s), use `console.log()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't enumerate an array with `for...in`.  `text1.split('.');` is producing an array, which you are trying to enumerate with `for...in`.  The value of `elem` on each iteration of the `for...in` is one of the the array indexes as a string ('0' on the first iteration, '1' on the second and so on).  You'll even end up with some of the Array prototype methods and other things up the prototype change.

For pre ES6 environments, try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sents.length; i++)
{
    tempC += 1;

    wordsC = sents[i].split(" ").length;
    wordsTot += wordsC;

    if (tempC == 2) {
        wordsC -= 1;
        wordsTot -= 1;
    }

    document.write("<br />Words:  " + wordsC + " |in sent: " + tempC + "  sent");
}
```

ES6 introduced a `for...of` construct which does what you're trying to do:

```
for (let elem of sents)
{
    tempC += 1;

    wordsC = elem.split(" ").length;
    wordsTot += wordsC;

    if (tempC == 2) {
        wordsC -= 1;
        wordsTot -= 1;
    }

    document.write("<br />Words:  " + wordsC + " |in sent: " + tempC + "  sent");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "There are five words here. I like turtles a lot. This is five words long. Yep.";
var split = str.split(".");
var amountOfSentences = str.charAt(str.length - 1) == "." ? split.length : split.length + 1;
var total = 0;

for (i = 0; i < amountOfSentences - 1; i++) {
    $("body").append("Sentence " + (i + 1) + ": ");
    for (j = 0; j < split[i].split(" ").length - 1; j++) {
        total++;
    }
    if (i == 0) total++;
    $("body").append(" " + total + "<br />");
    total = 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> There are five words here. I like turtles a lot. This is five words long. Yep.

This will output:

> Sentence 1: 5
>   Sentence 2: 5
>   Sentence 3: 5
>   Sentence 4: 1

The end of sentence can end with a dot or not, it doesn't matter (taken account for in the `var amountOfSentences`). Does that work out for you?

Comment: Great job, Snorlax.Thank you so much.

Comment: @ArtJ No problem! Please select my answer as the correct answer and upvote if you think it was good :)

Comment: @ArtJ No problem. You should be able to mark it as answer though :)

Comment: Snorlax's solution is the perfect answer to my problem. Issue resolved with flying colors. Congrats, Snorlax. I will reserve the right to ask you in the future if I get in trouble with more java/jquery programming.

Comment: Snorlax, I have a great confidence in you: would have a look at my question - highlight sentences that start with the same 2 words, javascript?

Comment: @ArtJ I would, but when I help you and you don't accept my answer as the correct one, I don't feel like I want to help you.

Comment: Snorlax, I already acknowledged your answer as the PERFECT solution. See above. Is there any other way?

Comment: Sorry Snorlax, I found it :-)))) The tick V next to it....It's really Rocket Science

Comment: @ArtJ You marked the other answer as the correct though. But sure, whatever floats your boat.